# How to send image via jQuery $.post(). Not $.ajax() into Spring servlet filter that rejects XSS attacks?

Tags: jquery, post, filter, xss

I have form `$('#frm')` where I have inputs like

```
<form id='frm'>
    <input name='name'>
    <input name='age'>
    <input type='file'>
    ...
</form>
```

Then I need to send this to the server.

On the server side I have Filter that blocks XSS scripts.

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Created by Djadiv on 13.09.2017.
 */
public class AntiScriptFilter implements Filter {

    static class FilteredRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        public FilteredRequest(ServletRequest request) {
            super((HttpServletRequest) request);
        }

        public String sanitize(String input) {

            System.out.println("---------------Original input: " + input);
            if (input != null) {
                input = input.replaceAll("<", "&lt;")
                        .replaceAll(">", "&gt;")
                        .replaceAll("&", "&amp;")
                        .replaceAll("\"", "&quot;")
                        .replaceAll("'", "&#x27;")
                        .replaceAll("/", "&#x2F;");


                System.out.println("---------------Sanitized input: " + input);
                return input;
            }

            return null;
        }


        public String getParameter(String paramName) {
            System.out.println("---------------getParameter/// name = " + paramName);
            String value = super.getParameter(paramName);
            System.out.println("---------------getParameter/// value of the param " + paramName + " = " + value);
            value = sanitize(value);
            return value;
        }

        public String[] getParameterValues(String paramName) {
            System.out.println("-------------------getParameterValues//// name = " + paramName);
            String values[] = super.getParameterValues(paramName);
            System.out.println("-------------------getParameterValues//// values for the parameter " + paramName + " = " + Arrays.toString(values));
            if (values != null) {
                for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
                    values[index] = sanitize(values[index]);
                }
            }
            return values;
        }

        public Map getParameterMap() {

            System.out.println("----------------getParameterMap");

            Map parameterMap = super.getParameterMap();
            Map parameters = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
            String[] p_values;

            Set<Map.Entry<String, String[]>> set = parameterMap.entrySet();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : set) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                String[] values = entry.getValue();
                p_values = new String[values.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    p_values[i] = sanitize(values[i]);
                }
                parameters.put(key, p_values);
            }
            return parameters;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        System.out.println("--------------init AntiScriptFilter");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("--------------doFilter AntiScriptFilter");

        try {
            chain.doFilter(new FilteredRequest(request), response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            request.setAttribute("errorMessage", ex);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/error/errorstatus.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("--------------destory AntiScriptFilter");
    }
}
```

I added that filter definition in my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>antiScriptFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>uz.dd.filters.AntiScriptFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>antiScriptFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

finally a have a JavaScript function

```
function save() {
 $.ajax({
            url: "./routes/save",
            data: new FormData($('#frm')[0]),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#frmDialog').modal('hide');
                    clearSearchParams();
                    getList();
                } else {
                    $.messager.alert('Внимание!', result.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But when I try save data from my form `$('#frm')` entering inot input something like

```
<script> alert('!!!') </script>
```

all that data comes into appropriate controller then goes to DB and successfully saves. But it doesn't come into my filter. And then on my page I get executing of

```
<script> alert('!!!') </script>
```

But if make like this

```
var formData = new FormData($('#frm')[0]);
$.post(
    "./routes/save",
    formData,
    function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            $('#frmDialog').modal('hide');
            clearSearchParams();
            getList();
        } else {
            $.messager.alert('Внимание!', result.msg);
        }
    },
    'JSON'
)
```

it gives me error in browser
[image: TypeError]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $.post is just a shorthand for $.ajax... In your ajax call, you have more options set, so I'd stick to it.

Comment: I know that! But I still can't figure out why behaviour of my filter with $.post  request differs from behaviour with $.ajax request???

Comment: I tried hinting that the behaviour cannot be expected t the exact same if you are using two different calls with different parameters...